# Can i use Watson TTS in my C++ project?

Tags: c++, text-to-speech, watson-conversation

I'm working on a chat bot in C++ on a Linux system and I just need to give it a voice.

I know Watson TTS is awesome, I can even work on the tone of the voice and customize it.

How can I use Watson TTS for my C++ project? I saw on the official website that the SDKs are available for Node, java, python, .Net, Unity and Salesforce.

Is there any way I can use it to read the answers of my chat bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the IBM Watson TTS service from a C++ program. AFAIK there is no SDK, but you have the [documented Watson TTS API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/text-to-speech/api/v1/#introduction) here. You would need to send the http requests via a C++ library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think/I haven't heard yet of using Watson's TTS for a C++ program. There are , though here you can see a top 5 of TTS working with C++ (https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-text-to-speech-library-for-C) .